# PHPにてfile_get_contentsでのIPv6の使用について（外部に出る際のIPの切り替え）

Tags: php, linux, centos, ipv6

環境はconohaのVPS(CentOS6.5)をレンタルしています。
PHPは5.6です。

conohaでは標準os(CentOS6.5)を選択した場合、17個IPv6がついてきます。
IPv4を追加するのは有料なので、できるだけIPv6を活用したいと思っています。

file_get_contentsにてコンテキストの使用が可能ということでPHPマニュアルにある以下のコードを試してみました。

```
<?php
$opts = array(
　　　　'socket' => array(
　　　　　　　　'bindto' => '[自環境のIPv6]:任意のポート',
　　　　),
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com', false, $context);

?>
```

上記のようにコンテキストを指定しても

- file_get_contents(): Invalid IP Address : [自環境のIPv6]

というエラーが出てしまいます。

以下状況です。

- 当該のIPv6は17個すべてDNS逆引きが可能な状態で設定は正しいものと思います。
- IPv6、17個すべて試しましたがエラーが出ます(省略表記・フル表記どちらも）。
- 別途追加したIPv4ではコンテキスト指定（IP切り替え）に成功しています。
- 接続先のサイトはIPv6に対応しています。

どのようにしたらPHPからIPv6にて外部に出ることができますでしょうか？
IP(IPv6にて)を切り替えてデータが取得できるのであれば方法はfile_get_contentsにこだわりはありません。

よろしくおねがいします。

追記　コメントにて確認頂いた件について情報を追加

- 1．ping6は成功しています。( ipv6.google.com等のサイトで成功）
- 2．ip6tablesの設定は以下です。

  :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] 
  :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0] 
  -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
  -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 546 -d [ 自環境のIPv6の帯域] -j ACCEPT 
  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-adm-prohibited 
  -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-adm-prohibited 
  COMMIT
- 3．ip6tablesを無効にしても出現するエラーに変化はありませんでした。
- 4．`php -i | grep -i ipv6`の試行結果については以下のようになりました。

  $ php -i | grep -i ipv6
  IPv6 Support => enabled
  IPv6 => Yes
- 5．PHPプログラムのbindtoの部分を`'bindto' => '[0]:0'` (osに任せる)にしてみる。

エラーは出なくなりますが、別途所有するサーバに以下のようなスクリプトを用意し接続してみると、取得できるのはインターフェスeth0に紐付いたVPSレンタル時に授与されるデフォルトのIPv4でした。

```
    <?php
    echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

- 6．'bindto' => '[::1]:0'の試行結果は以下のようになりました。

以下のようなエラーとなりました。

file_get_contents(): Invalid IP Address: ::1

上記5.で使用した別サーバのスクリプトにて取得できたIPはデフォルトのIPv4でした。

- 7．IPアドレスとして適切な形式になってるかの確認（全角文字の有無、省略表記の誤謬)

再度確認しましたが、全角文字等の不適当な文字は入っていませんでした。
::が:になっていないかについては、所有するIPv6にて0000で連続する領域が無いため記述はありません。
また、所有するIPv6にて「0090」のような「0」を省略できる箇所は複数ありますので、再度省略に間違いがないかを確認しました。また0を省略しないフル表記でも再度試行してみましたが、エラーは依然として出ています。

- 一応の解決？

結論から申しますと、コメントにて示唆いただいた「IPv6の直指定によるfile_get_contents」にて、IPv6コンテキスト切り替えが可能であることがわかりました。

IPv6の直指定であれば、エラーは出ず、なおかつ接続元のIPはIPv6になります。ドメイン指定でなぜエラーが出てしまうのかの疑問はありますが、現状では示唆していただいた方法で目的に叶うので一旦解決とさせていただきたいと思います。

たくさんの助言をいただきありがとう御座います。

Comment: ping6 などで IPv6 通信ができていることは確認ずみですか？

Comment: はい確認済みです。ipv6.google.com等へのping6成功しています。

Comment: 了解です。それでは ip6tables でブロックしている可能性も 無いと考えていいですか？

Comment: 申し訳ありません。ip6tablesの設定には自信がありませんが、以下のようにしています。おそらく外に出る場合とコネクションを確立した接続はブロックしていないとはおもうのですが、、どうでしょう（汗）

:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 546 -d [ 自環境のIPv6の帯域] -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-adm-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-adm-prohibited
COMMIT

Comment: それでしたら切り分けのため、一旦 ipv6tables を無効化してみると現象に変化は現れるか 確認できますか？

Comment: ipv6tables を無効化してみましたが、状況に変化はありませんでした。エラーも同じものがでます。

Comment: 追加情報はコメントではなく質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: >>taka88さん  
タグの編集ありがとう御座います。  
>>suzukisさん  
ご指摘いただいた件、質問の編集を行いました。

Comment: `'bindto'` の部分を `'bindto' => '[0]:0` にするとどうなるでしょうか？(OS 側の自動設定に任せる)

Comment: それと、`php -i | grep -i ipv6` を実行した場合の結果を教えていただけますか。

Comment: 頂いた質問での情報を追記しました。

Comment: 度々ですみませんが、`'bindto' => '[::1]:0'` ではどうなりますでしょうか。

Comment: @argusさん　試行してみました。結果は質問を編集して追記しています。

Comment: 127.0.0.1 や ::1 ではloopbackデバイスになってしまい、外部にアクセスできないと思います。別サーバや `example.com` の**v6アドレス**に対して、**contextを指定せずに** `file_get_contents` するとどうなるでしょうか？

Comment: @unaristさん
IPv6アドレスにて`file_get_contents`すると、`Invalid argumente`エラーが出てしまいます。`http://`付きと、念の為素のIPv6アドレスとで試行しましたが、どちらも同じ`Invalid argumente `エラーです。このエラーは不正なパラメータを表すものかと思いますが、`file_get_contents`でのIPv6アドレスの指定はどのように行えば良いかが恥ずかしながらわかりません。ご教授いただけますか？

Comment: 例えば ::1 であれば `file_get_contents('http://[::1]/')` となります。それでもやはり `Invalid argument` になるようなら、同じv6アドレスを `ping6 ::1` といった形で再度pingしてみてください。

Comment: @unaristさん　おそくなり大変申し訳ありません。示唆頂いた件、質問に情報を加えました。

Answer (score 1):

ソースコードを見ると"Invalid IP Address"になるのは文字列がIPアドレスとして適切な形式になっていない場合なので、その点を確認してください。

・全角文字を紛れ込ませていないか
・0を省略する`::`が`:`になっていないか

など

もう一つ、接続先がIPv4の場合、IPv6アドレスを表記していてもIPv4として解釈しようとしてやはり"Invalid IP Address"になります。

```
$ host www.google.com
www.google.com has address 173.194.126.209
www.google.com has address 173.194.126.212
www.google.com has address 173.194.126.208
www.google.com has address 173.194.126.210
www.google.com has address 173.194.126.211
www.google.com has IPv6 address 2404:6800:4004:808::1010

file_get_contents('http://www.google.com', false, $context);
// => no warning

$ host www.yahoo.co.jp
www.yahoo.co.jp is an alias for www.g.yahoo.co.jp.
www.g.yahoo.co.jp has address 182.22.72.251
www.g.yahoo.co.jp has address 183.79.197.250
www.g.yahoo.co.jp has address 183.79.198.79
www.g.yahoo.co.jp has address 183.79.227.90

file_get_contents('http://www.yahoo.co.jp', false, $context);
// => PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Invalid IP Address: (snip)
```

Comment: @suzukisさん
　ありがとうございます。ご回答いただいた件について試行してみました。情報は質問に追記しました。

Comment: @suzukisさん　接続先IPv6の直指定でエラーがでなくなることがわかりました。ありがとう御座います。